# Photo Report PHP Auto Save DB

Tags: php, ajax, database, image-processing, autosave

Good evening folks,

I have a mvc app where picture reports are created. So a user uploads pictures and then writes a description in a text box next to the picture. Sometimes these reports are very long and when there is an interrption (network signal lost, power cut, user hits back by mistake) the whole report is lost and the user has to start all over and its frustrating. So Id like to implement an auto save feature that also saves the picture information along with the descriptions so that the data is not lost is page if refreshed or power is cut... So would that be even possible with multiple pictures (about 40 per report)? Btw only image adresses are stored in the DB. And if its possible whats the best way, Ajax Auto Save?

Comment: This sounds a thought the localStorage object would best be suited for your purposes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend saving the report to the [browser's local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) as it's typed.

To clarify, I feel that this is more reliable than AJAX, as it doesn't require an internet connection or can't go wrong due to flaky internet.

As an alternative you could use a cookie, which may work in older browsers and provides an avenue for you to delete it from the PHP side of things.

Comment: Thank you! I just need to make sure its below 5 mb as local storage seems to have a limit of 5mb storage.

Comment: I think that might be plenty for your use case, I don't imagine that anyone would be writing a 5 million character report.

Comment: yeah but there are about 40 images per report and before submit is clicked pictures are not yet stored on server so they they would need to be stored with local storage right?

Comment: I'm not so sure about storing the images in local storage. I myself would consider just storing the text for each image, with the name of the image as the key used when storing, something like `localStorage.setItem('image-name.jpg', theReport);`. This way, you don't have to store the images in local storage, and can retrieve their report for each image as they're added again.

Comment: you're right I think it's best to proceed that way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.